# Incomplete sem:sparql results for Property Paths when "optimize=0"

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-8, propertypath

Consider the following subClassOf relations:

```
m1
|_ m1_1
   |_ m1_1_1
```

The following query correctly returns m1_1 and m1_1_1:

```
sem:sparql('
SELECT * 
WHERE { 
 ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>+ <http://example.org/people#m1> .
}', (), 
("optimize=1"))
```

However, the following query only returns m1_1:

```
sem:sparql('
SELECT * 
WHERE { 
 ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>+ <http://example.org/people#m1> .
}', (), 
("optimize=0"))
```

It's also the case with *.

After upgrading to MarkLogic 8.0-5.2, the previous sem:sparql queries return correct results but not when the object is a parameter. E.g. the following query doesn't return anything:

```
sem:sparql('
SELECT * 
WHERE {
?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>+ ?item . 
}',
(map:new ((map:entry ("item", sem:iri("http://example.org/people#m1"))))), 
("optimize=0"))
```

Comment: Without seeing your data, we can't reproduce this.  It could be, e.g., a typo in one of the class IRIs. (I doubt that it is, but this isn't a complete example that any one can use to test. )

Comment: What version of MarkLogic are you using?  On 8.0-5.2, I get the same results setting `optimize` to 1 or 0.

Comment: @scotthenninger: thanks for testing, I'm on 8.0-3.2.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: my data is as simple as I described, only two subClass relations between three URIs.

Comment: I tried on a pretty complex hierarchy with 15M triples.  Is it possible to upgrade?  There was some significant semantics work around 8.0-4.0.

Comment: @scotthenninger: yes. it's working fine on 8.0-5.2.

Comment: Excellent, I'll migrate to an answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @scotthenninger: After upgrading to MarkLogic 8.0-5.2, the previous sem:sparql queries return correct results but not when the object is a parameter passed to sem:sparql. I've added an example query to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possible workarounds:

```
sem:sparql('
SELECT * 
WHERE {
BIND (?param AS ?item) .
?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>+ ?item . 
}',
(map:new ((map:entry ("param", sem:iri("http://example.org/people#m1"))))), 
("optimize=0"))
```

Or

```
sem:sparql('
SELECT * 
WHERE {
?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>+ ?item . 
FILTER (?item = ?param) .
}',
(map:new ((map:entry ("param", sem:iri("http://example.org/people#m1"))))), 
("optimize=0"))
```

Comment: The filter approach also works very well when param contains a sequence of IRI's..

Answer (score 0):

Checking with a a fairly complex RDFS ontology using MarkLogic 8.0-5.2, this seems to work OK. Is it possible to upgrade? There was some significant semantics work around 8.0-4.0.